# CFBundleVersion key error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am using the Application Loader for the first time to upload my .ipa file to iTunes Connect...

I am receiving this error:

```
The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleVersion key.
The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleShortVersionString key.
```

How do I know if it contains the key?

Here is an image of my Info.plist file...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with CFBuildVersion and than i found that in my project Target there is no build version inserted.

So i have just inserted build version and issue solved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The file that you are showing contains these keys. You can see it if you open the file via TextEdit. Also I have noticed that this file is located not in the root folder of the project. Maybe the project has another Info.plist file that is located in the root folder and is checked by Application Loader. Please check.